# Convert lable into dropdown using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a Label and onclick on label I want to convert label into dropdown list. Using jQuery and value in the dropdown will come from database. Suppose some linq method.

Comment: Do you plan to use Ajax on Click to return the data for the drop down or are you loading the drop down list data on page load and just keeping it hidden?

Comment: I am loading it on page load when user edit or click on lable.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a jsfiddle that when you click the label it makes an Ajax call and with the results creates a select/option dropdown and replaces the original label:

http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/QBafQ/1/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label id="someLabel">Click me</label>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#someLabel").click(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            json: "[{ \"value\": \"value1\", \"html\": \"html 1\" }, { \"value\": \"value1\", \"html\": \"html 2\" }]"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var select = $("<select>");
            $.each(data, function(i, option) {
                select.append($("<option>", {
                    value: option.value,
                    html: option.html
                }));
            });

            label.replaceWith(select);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanx Adam..but is there any way to fill data in the dropdown without json.because i already have a method GetData() which is giving me list of value. which i want to insert into the dropdown.

Comment: What does your GetData() return (html/xml?)?  If you send me the exact contents then I will update my example.

Comment: In GetData() method i am firing linq to sql query to fetch the data from database.so this method giving me list of some feilds which i want to show in the dropdown.exp...GetData(){return list;}here list contain fields which i want to show in dropdown.